# Submitting special characters, like "š č ć đ ž", over the webform in grails app

Tags: mysql, grails, utf-8, spring-security, special-characters

I'm developing grails app , connected to MySql database ... I have created database with utf-8 character set and with that collation ... also by default character-set is set to utf-8 on mysql server ... but I defined it explicitly for my schema

In grails app I defined in Datasource.groovy

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blabla?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8"
```

also in Config.groovy

```
grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

in my .gsp files I added

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

So when I try to create new User via views/user/create.gsp , and in some field I input characters š, č, đ, ć, or ž ... the value inserted in database is something like ÄÄÄ ... but I want the value to be ččč

When I insert new user through SQL statment in MySql Workbench , it is saved as I want it with field value "ččč" , when I load that user on my list.gsp,  or show.gsp I can see in browser ččč ...

So the problem is somewhere in the process when saving User via webform...
Can anyone help ?

P.S. I don't know if it is relevant, but when I type these characters in textfield on a webform I switch my keyboard from EN (English) to SR (Serbian Latin) in Language bar in Windows

Grails 1.3.7

STS 2.8.1

mysql-connector-java-5.1.18

Windows 7

Comment: If the question was successfully answered you should mark the working answer as such for the benefit of those who come asking the same/similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work by using `<g:uploadForm >` tag instead of `<g:form>` , and within it, regular `<g:textfield>` for values I wanted to save. Beside that everything else is Grails generated, like DataSource.groovy, Config.groovy, my *.gsp files, like I explained them in question  ... Does anyone know difference between these 2 tags?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is caused by a Grails plugin, specifically "webxml" plugin version 1.4.

You need to upgrade that plugin in your project like this:

1. Stop your Grails application if it's running.
2. Go to "%USERHOME%.grails\1.3.7\projects\%YOUR_PROJECT%\plugins" folder where %YOUR_PROJECT% is your project's name, and %USERHOME% on Windows 7 is "C:\Users\YOUR_NAME".
3. There should be a folder named "webxml-1.4". Delete it.
4. Go to your Grails project folder.
5. Type "grails install-plugin webxml" and confirm the upgrade to 1.4.1 if asked.
6. Run your application - non-English letters will now be correctly interpreted even under scaffolding.

Comment: Can you please look at my question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111144/upgrading-webxml-1-4-to-1-4-1)

Answer (score 0):

Put a `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag on your page if you're using HTML5, and set the attribute `accept-charset="UTF-8"` on your form elements.  It seems to be necessary to reliably get your forms submitted in UTF-8 with all browsers.

Comment: Ok, I've tried what newtover said , still not working. Then I added meta tags on my page and accept-charset = "UTF-8" within g:textfield tag like you said, not enough. @webarto can you please be more specific where do I put this "SET NAMES UTF8" statement, is it in DataSource.groovy, and how do I define it.
Also, while debugging I noticed, that when I stop process in my UserController in save action, userInstance which is created by def userInstance = new User(params) , I see that it is already the field in question encoded as ÄÄÄ and not ččč ... userInstance.save(flush: true) goes after

Comment: Just run a SQL query after connecting to database, you need to set connection collation to UTF8, bre...

Comment: @webarto nope, that's not it :(

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
SET NAMES UTF8
```

after connect.

Comment: How to do this in grails that hadles database connection automagically? It has Datasource.groovy file which handles all the connection for you so you never call database just do the coding.

Comment: Like @drago said , I also need this in Datasource.groovy