# Upgrading webxml 1.4 to 1.4.1

Tags: grails, dependencies, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have an irritating problem with webxml plugin. I need version 1.4.1. I have webxml 1.4 and when I try to upgrade it from STS 2.8.1 it gets upgraded but it's like it rolls back the changes immediately. I also tried upgrading it from Grails console and from command prompt. When I upgrade webxml from command promt it gets upgraded but then in STS I lose dependencies. And when I refresh dependencies from Grails tools STS downgrades webxml to 1.4. Please help.

- Grails 1.3.7
- STS 2.8.1

Plugins:

- calendar 1.2.1
- hibernate 1.3.7
- mail 1.0-SNAPSHOT
- spring-security-core 1.2.6
- tomcat 1.3.7

Comment: Does it make any difference if you define the webxml dependency in your BuildConfig.groovy?

Comment: @david Thanks for advice david. I tried that allready but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's coming from the spring-security-core dependencies - update spring-security-core to 1.2.7.1.